# Trouble using BeautifulSoup Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I keep on getting a traceback whether I use bs4, `beautifulsoup4` or BeautifulSoup

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
```

On terminal I get

```
Peters-Mac-mini:~ admin$ pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

This is the first time that I am attempting to use BeautifulSoup, but I have never experienced this error with other installations. Don't know how to get out of it! I have not seen this problem amongst the Stack Overflow posts.

Comment: `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` would work for bs3. For bs4 use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @tanaydin: that is **absolute nonsense**. BeautifulSoup 4 *uses* lxml if it is installed instead. Both APIs have their merits.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import from `bs4`, not `BeautifulSoup`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 0):

Module names is not always the same in each versions.

This would help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

If you a want *cross platform* style of importing `BeautifulSoup`

You could do like this:

```
try:
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
except ImportError:
   from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: I get :>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4' I don't know what I have done

Comment: From: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup. I removed BeautifulSoup and reinstalled. in my /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages , I have both folders.  beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py3.2.egg-info and bs4. I assume that BeautifulSoup is in the init file in the bs4 folder

Comment: If I use the second example I get an Import Error neither modules exist

Comment: I used > help() > modules . Should I see beautiful soup in the list of modules? There is nothing there